# VB.net XAML UWP Can Shared Class Be Used for DataContext?

Tags: vb.net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an object of a class that I have declared 'shared' and am having trouble with getting the data binding working.  I believe my syntax is correct so I just want to ask a basic question whether a shared object can be used as a datacontext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654(v=vs.110).aspx#Static) says:

> Static (shared) classes in C# and modules in Visual Basic have static
>   (shared) members only and cannot be instantiated.

And here [about the DataContext property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext):

> A typical use of DataContext is to set it directly to a data source
>   object. This data source might be an instance of a class such as a
>   business object.

So, DataContext in UWP can only be set to an instance of an object. In WPF we can use shared (static) classes as a binding source, but not in UWP. You need an object.

I recommend creating another class that would provide access to members of your shared (static) class members.

Comment: Thank you.  Very clear answer.  Stating the difference between UWP and WPF helped explain it in my particular scenario.